# .Rlib and .d file instead of .wasm

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, rust-wasm

I want to compile a `.rs` file in a Rust lib to a `.wasm`.

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Instead of a `.wasm` file I get a `.Rlib` and `.d` file. What do I need to change to get a `.wasm`?

Comment: I would recommend using [wasm-pack](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rustc` considers `.wasm` files to fill the “native dynamic library” role in the WASM target. Add this to your `Cargo.toml` configuration to request that build instead of the default `.rlib`:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

Comment: if you are just using rustc (for whatever reason), the `crate-type=cdylib` flag can be used

Comment: May i ask, what does the .rlib file useful for? Does it have any application? And how does the compiler know, when cdylib crate type is used , the output should be a .wasm file and without it the default .rlib is built for wasm32 target?

Comment: @raj `.rlib` is the default kind of output for any Rust _library._ Its purpose is to be the compiled static library which the Rust compiler will use as input when compiling crates that _depend on_ this crate.